React Native Error : java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace
What went wrong:

java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Sreya\Desktop\sreya\love-knot\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-a4bfdb9a-3a8e-40d1-895b-328f0f4c6181) to immutable location (C:\Users\Sreya\Desktop\sreya\love-knot\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)

I tried to clean Gradle with .\gradlew clean and also upgraded my Gradle version, but that still didn't resolve the issue.

What version of Gradle were you using, and what version did you upgrade to that did not resolve the issue?

I just got the same error and was able to solve it by changing just one character.
you need to change the gradle version.
your price is 8.6 or 8.7. Lower it to 8.5
change gradle wrapper properties :
YourApp/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties : distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip


I swear I always get issues like this almost every RN project I make. Why can't the maintainers make everything work fine once and then not change it? I'd rather not get extra features if it will make me unable to build

Thank you, it worked for me by changing the gradle version from 8.6 to 8.5.
For you FYI:
This is my React-native Version: 0.74.3
This is my node version: 18.16.1
This is my JDK Version: java 17.0.11 2024-04-16 LTS

Is this just a bug with Jetbrains IDE's, or is it a gradle bug? Got this when upgrading to 8.9. Reverting to 8.8 fixed it. I'm using IntelliJ

When change to 8.5 it gives error '> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'. > Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.7. Current version is 8.5. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl '

@Bills see my post

If you don't want to change the gradle version, you can try below steps :
Inside your project directory run this command:
npx react-native doctor

if the output is this:

type :
npx react-native run-android

then:
npm start --reset-cache

you might get this error:

you can resolve this by adding port in composer.json file

Now type:
npm start --reset-cache

hope this helps.

This was the solution for me.  It doesn't find Android Studio and all I had to do was reset the gradle cache and run it again.  No gradle changes needed.  8.6 works fine.

in my case I first had to kill all nodejs processes  taskkill /f /im node.exe

If I try this I get "Command 'npx' not found". I don't want to install any third party tools, I just want Android Studio to work.

I encountered this issue when I upgraded to Gradle 8.6. I fixed it by Changing the from 8.6 to 8.5.

This doesn't work. That gives an error that the minimum supported Gradle version is 8.7.

Update September 2024
Use Gradle Version 8.11 source
In your gradle.properties change to 8.11
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.11.1-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

Remove your .gradle folder from your project. To force the reinstall of the gradle distribution.

This doesn't fix the problem.

@DonaldDuck remove .gradle folder in your project to download the new version

@​lupaulus I did but it didn't help.

For new people to android, to archieve running the

File ->New ->New project

On:

Android Studio Jellyfish 2023.3.1, April 12, 2024 built

You will have to face:

java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace
(/my/folder/MyApplicationtestnew/.gradle/8.6/dependencies-accessors/4b...b9)
to immutable location
(/my/folder/MyApplicationtestnew/.gradle/8.6/dependencies-accessors/4b...fb)

Could not move temporary workspace (/my/folder/MyApplicationtestnew/.gradle/8.6/dependencies-accessors/4b...b9)
to immutable location
(/my/folder/MyApplicationtestnew/.gradle/8.6/dependencies-accessors/4b...fb)


I had to change from

/my/folder/MyApplication/gradle/libs.versions.toml

agp = "8.4.0"
To->
agp = "8.3.0"
And from

/my/folder/MyApplication/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip
To->
todistributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip

Easy Solution to Resolve React Native Error: java.io.UncheckedIOException - Could not move temporary workspace

Locate the Gradle Wrapper Configuration File: Navigate to your React Native project directory and find the gradle-wrapper.properties file. It's typically located in the android/gradle/wrapper directory of your project.

Open the gradle-wrapper.properties File: Use a text editor to open the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Find the distributionUrl Line: Look for a line in the file that starts with distributionUrl=. This line specifies the URL from which the Gradle distribution will be downloaded.

Identify the Current Gradle Version: The distributionUrl contains the URL for the current version of Gradle. It might look something like this:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip


Downgrade Gradle Version: Change the version number in the URL to a previous version where the error didn't occur. For example:
Previous version (e.g., Gradle 8.5):
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip


Save the Changes: After modifying the distributionUrl, save the changes to the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Run Gradle Tasks: Run your Gradle tasks again. Gradle will now download and use the specified version (e.g., 8.5) instead of the problematic one.


By following these steps, you can resolve the java.io.UncheckedIOException error related to the temporary workspace in your React Native project.

This doesn't work. That gives an error that the minimum supported Gradle version is 8.7.

react-native: 0.74.3
run this command Inside your project directory.

npm start --reset-cache

then:

npx react-native run-android


Thanks, this worked for me. But maybe you should explain: You run the command:
$: npm start --reset-cache I ended the command  after it has ran successfully and then I ran:
$: npx react-native run-android and it worked fine for me.
Thanks!

I had to install the latest version of Android Studio, switch gradle-wrapper.properties to 8.5 from 8.6, let Android Studio do gradle build (or whatever it does with gradle), then switch back to 8.6, start the emulator through Android Studio, and then it just worked.
All these steps are definitely not required as I had encountered this issues a day or two ago and it fixed itself pretty quickly just by deleting the folder with the issue.
It could definitely be an emulator issue as the emulator that was launched was completely clean.

If you have this issue recently with react-native version 0.75.x
First try to run

npm run android
npm run start

If the issue still exists

remove node_modules, yarn.lock or package-lock.json and android/.gradle
yarn install or npm install
cd android && ./gradlew --stop
./gradlew clean
npx react-native run-android in the root of the project

Source

Awesome, thank you very much!

@MarlonDSC, you are welcome.

I have just updated the gradle version to 8.3.
like this,
change gradle wrapper properties : YourApp/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties : distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip

I faced the same error!
Solution:

cd android > gradlew clean
npx react-native run-android

I didn't change the gradle version

In my case I had run yarn start before yarn android.
I closed the terminal which had yarn start (metro).
Then I ran the yarn android, it worked as expected.

To resolve the issue, change the folder name from:
423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-a4bfdb9a-3a8e-40d1-895b-328f0f4c6181 
to:
423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a
Repeat this process as needed, and it will work!

@react-native/gradle-plugin Please add it as a devDependency first then try to run your app.

just downgrade from 8.6 to 8.4
and then clean gradle it will work
gradleanddistributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip

try following steps:

quit Android Studio;
delete .gradle directory for the project;
start gradle by ./gradew.bat --daemon in command line for the project;
restart Android Studio.....



To gather additional information, modify the file located at apps\APPNAME\android\gradlew.bat as follows:
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %* --info --stacktrace --scan --debug to get more insights.

The error:
Here's the error encountered:
Could not move temporary workspace (D:\src\AAAAA.ReactNative_01\apps\DemoApp2\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-7cac1f26-dea7-442e-a56f-947d494ffd6a) to immutable location (D:\src\AAAAA.ReactNative_01\apps\DemoApp2\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a), attempting copy-then-move         java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\src\AAAAA.ReactNative_01\apps\DemoApp2\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-7cac1f26-dea7-442e-a56f-947d494ffd6a -> D:\src\AAAAA.ReactNative_01\apps\DemoApp2\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a



I found that node.exe blocks several directories.
D: Drive is the DEV drive.
Windows Defender is turned off (it was always on, but I disabled it only for testing purposes).
Everything worked perfectly fine yesterday. No idea what's changed overnight. This setup has been working for around 9 months, including the 8.6 version, which I started using since RN 0.74.
Windows' LongPath is enabled.
The repository was cleaned multiple times using git clean -xfd && git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -xfd.
GRADLE_HOME is located on the D drive, and the caches have been cleaned multiple times.
Tried running VS Code with Admin permissions — no change.
Tried moving the directory manually — encountered a Windows error. See the screenshots below.



Still trying to figure out what’s going on...
However, I’m almost certain that Windows Defender is not the source of the issue, especially in my case. It could be due to some Windows Update, but I'm not sure. The only update I got today is:

However, it seems that I encountered the issue slightly earlier (it's 00:50 on 22-SEP-2024 right now), and I've been trying to solve this for about 5 hours, starting from 21-SEP-2024.
UPD:
Well...
I decided to try a newer version of Gradle. I went to apps\DemoApp2\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties and changed the version to 8.10 (the specific version doesn’t matter).
When I opened this file, my VS Code began initializing a Java project (it has the Java plugin installed and enabled). Initially, I closed VS Code out of frustration and reopened it to try Gradle version 10+ by executing the yarn start .... It didn’t help, so I switched back to the previous version in the file.
This time, I decided to wait for the build result, which was displayed as progress in VS Code. It finished without errors. I was surprised.
I then tried running the project as usual, and you can see the result in the screenshots below.
I have no clue what happened, but I’m almost certain that it’s neither Windows Defender nor Windows Updates.


PS


I install  Jdk 17
I had the same error but after several hours I resolve it
I  change gradle version:
change gradle wrapper properties : YourApp/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties : distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
I first changed to gradle-8.6-all.zip it does not work  the  gradle-8.3-all.zip
work for me
For more, you can check gradlew, gradlew.bat changes : https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.73.7&to=0.74.0
