React native- build failed
I am getting this kind of error while building in react-native, how should I resolve it??
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\user5\firstProject\myProject\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-c277e679-a28e-44d0-b6ad-1c03f9ff0a6b) to immutable location (C:\Users\user5\firstProject\myProject\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)


Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\user5\firstProject\myProject\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-c277e679-a28e-44d0-b6ad-1c03f9ff0a6b) to immutable location (C:\Users\user5\firstProject\myProject\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)

I tried by running npx react-native doctor, it shows 0 errors and 0 warnings but still after running the command npx react-native run-android, build failed.

check out the answers here , hope you'll resolve, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78384724/react-native-error-java-io-uncheckedioexception-could-not-move-temporary-work
